# Add vector to array in R

Tags: r, arrays, tensorflow, matrix, vector

I have an array

```
width.ndvi <- 51
height.ndvi <- 51
totalframes <- 4464
ndvi.array <- array(0, dim = c(height.ndvi, width.ndvi, totalframes))
```

giving `[1:51, 1:51, 1:4464]` as the structure of the array. I would like to bind a vector

`channel <- rep(1, 4464)`

to `ndvi.array` as the last dimension of the array, so the result has the format

`[1:51, 1:51, 1:4464, 1:4464]`

However, I may only need an array of `[1:51, 1:51, 1:4464, 1]`, not entirely sure. The final dimension should always have a value of 1, it specifies that the 51x51 image is greyscale, not RBG where the channel value could be between 1 to 3.

Comment: just do `array(rep(ndv.array,length(channel)),c(dim(ndvi.array),length(channel)))`

Comment: You seem to be mixing values and dimensions. You start with an array that has dimensions 51x51x4464. This is equiavalent to 51x51x4464x1. (Just as a 2-dimensional 2x3 matrix could be considered a 3-dminsional 2x3x1 array). What are the dimensions of your desired result?

Comment: I believe I need 51x51x4464x1. This is input for tensorflow keras, where a channel dimension needs to be specified.

Comment: Thanks Onyambu, turns out I don't need a 4464 length vector, just a single value of 1 but by setting ```channel <-1``` I got an array of ```[1:51, 1:51, 1:4464, 1]```